# Extending a function to be continuous

Tags: functions, continuity

My question is as follows:

How do I determine whether it is possible to extend a function f

$f(x) = {\sqrt x}(\pi + sin(\pi/x))$

to a continuous function over [0, $+\infty$).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This is defined for all $ x \neq 0 $ so is continuous except at that point Given sine can only take values between -1 and +1 and the square root of 0 is 0 I would set the value of the function to zero at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x)$ is defined and continuos on $(0,\infty)$.

$0\le |f(x)|=|√x(π+\sin (π/x)| \le √x(π+|\sin (π/x)|)\le √x(π+1);$

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}|f(x)|=0$, hence

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}f(x)=0$.

Define the continuos extension on $[0,\infty)$:

$f(x)=√x(π+\sin (π/x))$ for $x >0$

$f(x)=0$ for $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\pi+\sin (\frac {\pi} x)$ is bounded, $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0+$ and  you can extend  $f$ continuously  by defining $f(0)$ to be $0$.